# TypeScript interface with multiple call signatures

Tags: function, typescript, interface, overloading

I saw in TypeScript 2.2 the option for "overloading" function by defined Interface call signatures and I spent quite a time to understand how to use it.

so after working on it and "cracking" it I thought it will be worth to post it here.

the issue I started with was, for example:

```
interface Func1 {
    (num1: number, num2: number): number;
    (str1: number, str2: string): string;
}

function F1(num1: number, num2: number): number {
    return num1 + num2;
}

const f1: Func1 = F1;
console.log(f1(1, 2));
```

but the compiler did not pass it because the `Func1` can't accept the `F1` function.

I want to make overloading and I don't know what to do.

see answer below.

Answer (score 13):

after digging it I found we can do quite of overloading. Overloading in TypeScript is not different from any other JavaScript code. it must be implemented in **one** function and not in multiple ones, like in `C++`. you need to make your function accept all options.

for example:

```
interface Func1 {
    (v1: number, v2: number): number;
    (v1: string, v2: string): string;
}

const f1: Func1 = (v1, v2): any => {
    return v1 + v2;
};
console.log(f1("1", "2"));
console.log(f1(1, 2));
```

the function `f1` suppose to have types for all options of overloading interface call signature, if you set strong type it will block you because of the types are not castable. like in this example `number` not castable to `string`.

you also can create multiple functions which use of the interface call signature overloading and pass those to your `f1` and if the type match it will pass. just make sure your function can handle all the interface call signature.

it important to check types in implemented function when using classes or if the function parameters are not simple, like above example, using `typeof` and control all options.

hope it helped.

Comment: `typeof` is only meaningful on "simple" types though. Do _not_ check with `instanceof` you are writing a bad API if you do. I can and will call your API using something that is not an `instanceof` your class and you will not be able to prevent it.

Comment: What if I want to make overloading with different generic arguments? e.g. `interface GenericIdentityFn {
    <T>(arg: T): T;
    <T, F>(arg1: T, arg2: F): [T, F];
}`

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow Multiple interface with the same name merge by default, so do their generics (also by name). `interface I<A>, interface I<A,B>, interface I<C> == interface I<A,B,C>`.

Comment: "Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number' and 'string | number'."